# Converting a loop from Matlab to C

Tags: c, matlab

I have a (3x5) matrix and I want to get its reduced row echelon form.
I want to implement it in C, so I first impelemnted it in Matlab like follows:

```
[L,U]=lu(a);
[m,n]=size(U);
disp('convert elements in major diagonal to 1')
  for s=1:m
  U(s,:)=U(s,:)/U(s,s);
  end
  for j=m:-1:2
   for i=j-1:-1:1
   U(i,:)=U(i,:)-U(j,:)*(U(i,j)/U(j,j));
 end
 end
```

The above code and rref function gave the same result.
When converting this code to C, I successfully implemented the LU decomposition and the conversion of elements in major diagonal to 1 but when imlemented these nested loops

```
for j=m:-1:2
   for i=j-1:-1:1
   U(i,:)=U(i,:)-U(j,:)*(U(i,j)/U(j,j));
 end
 end
```

as follows:

```
for(j=m-1;j>0;j--){
 for(i=j-1;i=0;i--){
     for(k=0;k<n;k++){
       U[i*n+k]=U[i*n+k]-(U[j*n+k]*(U[i*n+j]/U[j*n+j]));
        }
       }
      }
```

I got a wrong result. How to correct it please?

Comment: @mch: That's a correct translation as matlab uses 1 based indexing and c uses 0 based indexing.

Comment: @Daniel yes, i forgot. `for(i=j-1;i=0;i--)` should be `for(i=j-1;i>=0;i--)`. So the loop sets `i` to `0` and terminate before the first iteration.

Comment: @mch Thank you..when I corrected the error that you pointed and placed  *(U[i*n+j]/U[j*n+j]) outside the inner loop as Daniel answered, it works correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a closer look at your inner loop. As soon as you reach k=j you write the element `U[i*n+j]` or `U(i,j)` and use this updated value in all following iterations. Your matlab code uses the old value because you implemented vectorized operations. If you calculate `*(U[i*n+j]/U[j*n+j])` outside the inner loop it should be fine.